# How do I check property of next item in each/do loop in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Using RoR, I would like a helper to write a table of contents menu where root sections are dropdown menus for their subsections. In an each/do loop I would need to check if a section has subsections before outputting `class="dropdown"` on li and `class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"` on the link.

Is there a way to check the properties of the next item (if any) in an each/do loop? Or do I need to switch to a loop with an index?

Here's my table of contents helper as is.

```
def showToc(standard)
  html = ''
  fetch_all_sections(standard).each do |section|
    html << "<li>" << link_to("<i class=\"icon-chevron-right\"></i>".html_safe + raw(section[:sortlabel]) + " " + raw(section[:title]), '#s' + section[:id].to_s) << "</li>"
    end
  end
  return html.html_safe
end
```

Comment: Why doesn't `fetch_all_sections` return the data in a more natural form such as a tree? That would solve your problem without any chicanery.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I could get all root sections, use an each loop, then use fetch_all_sections to get that section's subsections in another loop. fetch_all_sections returns all sections in a list with a depth variable so I can also use the same method to output the whole document.

Comment: The answer in this particular case needs to take depth into account to output </ul> and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to have `class="dropdown"` on the `<li>` and `class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"` on the link not affect the anchor tag. Therefore, in this case, I can just check if section depth is 0 and act accordingly. The other answers are probably more relevant to most people but here's what worked for me.

```
def showToc(standard, page_type, section = nil, nav2section = false, title = nil, wtf=nil)
  html = ''
  new_root = true

  fetch_all_sections(standard).each do |section|
    if section[:depth] == 0
      if !new_root
        # end subsection ul and root section li
        html << "</li>\n</ul>"
        new_root = true
      end
      html << "<li class=\"dropdown\">" << link_to("<i class=\"icon-chevron-right\"></i>".html_safe + raw(section[:sortlabel]) + " " + raw(section[:title]), '#s' + section[:id].to_s, :class => "dropdown-toggle", :data => {:toggle=>"dropdown"})
    else
      # write ul if new root
      if new_root
        new_root = false
        html << "<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">\n" << "<li>" << link_to(raw(section[:sortlabel]) + " " + raw(section[:title]), '#s' + section[:id].to_s) << "</li>"
      else
        html << "<li>" << link_to(raw(section[:sortlabel]) + " " + raw(section[:title]), '#s' + section[:id].to_s) << "</li>"
      end
    end
  end
  return html.html_safe
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the abstraction [Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons). An example:

```
>> xs = [:a, :b, :c]
>> (xs + [nil]).each_cons(2) { |x, xnext| p [x, xnext] }
[:a, :b]
[:b, :c]
[:c, nil]
```

That said, note your code is full of unidiomatic Ruby, you should probably post it to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for review.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm reading your question correctly -- lets say fetch_all_sections(standard) returns an enumerable, such as Array, you could add a custom iterator to get what you want:

```
class Array
   #yields |current, next|
   def each_and_next
      @index ||= 0
      yield [self[@index], self[@index +=1]] until (@index == self.size)
      @index = 0
   end
end
```

p.s. I like @tokland's inline answer

---

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a.each_and_next { |x,y| puts "#{x},#{y}" }

produces:
1,2
2,3
3,4
4,
```